# Formula to update cell based on user changing another cell's content

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I want to know if there is a formula to update a cell in Excel with today's date

- when a user changes any value in the row that contains that cell

**OR**

- when a user changes the value of 6 / 7 / 8 specific cells (which happen to be on the same row).

Getting today's date is fairly easy using `A1 = today()`, but how do I get this to happen on user update as described above?

Comment: Is the workbook set to automatic calculation?

Comment: no. Could I use that to detect a cell's content change?

Comment: You will need to incorporate VBA for this. Excel is set to automatically update everything anytime any cell changes. The only way around this is to set calculation mode to manual. Next you need a trigger event to trigger the manual update other than clicking the update button. This is where you will need VBA to create such a trigger.  Would you like help writing such an event or are you against using VBA?

Comment: I think it'd be easier to drop the formula altogether and just use VBA to set the static value in the cell. It sounds like you want a "date updated" field or something. That's not too hard if you're familiar with VBA. The `Worksheet_Change` event can act as the trigger. Use `INTERSECT` to detect if they've changed cells you care about and then run the code to update the date value. Take a stab at that and come back with questions.

Comment: Before you spend a lot of time on formula or VBA, turn on automatic calculation to see if that solves this for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for row#7.  Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A7").EntireRow
    If Intersect(R, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        R.Cells(1, 1).Value = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If anything is changed in row#7, **A7** will be updated with today's date.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**